# login screen not appearing only header ionic framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile app and I am fairly new to AngularJS and Ionic. I am having trouble with my login page loading or my tabs. It appeared once and then it only shows the nav bar when I run it in ionic serve lab. Can someone help please please please? Here's a snippet of my code.

app.js

```js
angular.module('BooksterU', ['ionic','ionic.service.core', 'ionic.service.analytics', 'BooksterU.controllers', 'BooksterU.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicAnalytics) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $ionicAnalytics.register();
      
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider
  
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/user/login.html'
  })
  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');


});
```

login.html

```html
<ion-view view title="login" name="login-view">
    <ion-content padding="true" scroll="true" class="has-header">
        <form class='list'>
            <ion-list>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="creds.username">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="creds.password">
                </label>
            </ion-list>
            <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
            <a  ng-click="doLoginAction()"  class="button button-stable button-block">Log in</a>
            <a ui-sref='signup' class="button button-positive button-clear button-block">Create an account</a>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Bookster University</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <!-- Cordova is bootstrapped by ionic-platform-web-client, uncomment this if you remove ionic-platform-web-client... -->
    <!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script>-->

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="BooksterU">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class=" bar bar-header bar-energized">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(', /login');` and not `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');`?

Comment: @theblindprophet its supposed to be  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login'); I changed it thanks for noticing.

Comment: @theblindprophet no :( I wish someone could help out.

Comment: @TyrieceMcGlawn May be it is because your serve problem check in postmant of your json object and check in browser logs and tell me the result